# How to connect to MySQL database in docker container from Vagrant box?

Tags: mysql, laravel, symfony, docker, vagrant

I have a Symfony project which I'm running in 3 docker containers:

- A PHP-FPM container
- A NginX container
- A MySQL container

I have another (Laravel) project which is running through the pre-packaged Vagrant Box setup (Homestead).

I'm now trying to connect to the MySQL database (of the Docker setup) from within the Vagrant box of my Laravel project.

What I know for sure:

- I can connect to my MySQL database from my host machine through Sequel Pro.

Host: 127.0.0.1
Port: 3306

What I don't know:

- Which host / port should I define in my Laravel project in order to successfully connect to the MySQL database from my docker container setup?

Comment: Just try ip of the docker host (your workstation?) and port 3306 .. if you can connect from your pc it should work.

Comment: Works. Thanks you!

Comment: @opHASnoNAME I think you should post that as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can connect from your Workstation in should also work from the VM.

Simply use as connection parameter:

- IP: Your Workstation IP
- Port: 3306

Important: Publish the port of the Container with : -p 3306:3306

Comment: how to find my Workstation IP macbook ?